# Flow towards a stationary large objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

Consider such a flow heading towards the surface of a stationary and impenetrable
object. Apparently, a stagnation point will be produced as shown in the figure. 
[image]

I am trying to solve for the flow in the vicinity of the stagnation point.
I am assuming I can use Laplace equation for the velocity potential: $$ \nabla^2 \phi = 0  $$
The form of the solution I am guessing is $$ \phi = A x^2 +B y^2+C z^2 $$
I just can't figure out what the boundary conditions are. The $ \vec{u} = 0 $ at the origin is the only thing I can think of, but I don't think this is providing me anything actually useful.

The anwser to the problem provided has this form: $$ \phi = W(x^2+y^2-2z^2) $$
This satisfies the B.C. at the surface (flow normal to surface is zero). And gives zero velocity at stagnation point. I have no more boundary conditions given in the actual problem statement, so I am guessing they should be inferred.

Comment: Is the object a flat plate, or does it have curvature to it?

Comment: @TRF I don't think it matters here, I think the point is to treat the object in the vicinity of the stagnation point as locally flat.

Comment: I think this problem is already solved in _Fluid Mechanics_ by Landau & Lifshitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out I was missing something completely obvious. The solution must satisfy zero flow at stagnation point and the rotational symmetry around the z-axis. Zero flow at stagnation point is already satisfied. To satisfy rotational symmetry of the problem, the solution must have this form:
$$ \phi = Ax^2+Ay^2+Cz^2$$
i.e. both $x^2$ and $y^2$ must have I the same coefficient in front of them. 
Then, just from $$\nabla^2\phi =0 $$
I get $$ A+A+C=0, C=-2A$$

Answer (score 0):

First the velocity at the surface is parallel to the surface, or the surface would not be impenetrable.

Also unless the flow is frictionless, velocity is 0 at the surface.

Comment: The OP assumes that his flow is a potential flow, and thus frictionless. Only the normal component of the velocity vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

For potential flow, on the solid surface your boundary condition is

$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial \mathbf n}={\mathbf n}\cdot\nabla\phi=0$$

where $\mathbf n$ is the surface normal vector. You also need boundary conditions at all other boundaries, which come from your free-stream velocity conditions. This is typically something of the form

$$\nabla\phi={\mathbf u}_0$$,

where ${\mathbf u}_0$ is your free-stream velocity.

P.S.: In the vicinity of the stagnation point, assuming the object you are talking about can locally be approximated as just a plane surface with flow normal to it, the potential flow solution is given by

$$\phi(r,\theta)=C\, r^2 \cos(2\theta)$$

in polar coordinates, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$.

Comment: What about z-axis?

Comment: Also, I don't think free stream velocity is a valid B.C. here, as I am only looking at the approximation near the stagnation point

Comment: The example above is for the 2-D case; I don't have the 3-D case handy right now. On your second question, you are trying to solve a Laplace equation. This requires boundary conditions *everywhere* on the boundary of the domain in question. Having a uniform freestream velocity everywhere at infinity is a perfectly suitable boundary condition, but you are of course free to choose different boundary conditions appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description for non-lifting potential flow around a cylinder, which might be helpful depending on what exactly you are seeking. Below is an image of the potential flow solution and superposition required to "build" such a flowfield subject to the Laplace equation. It requires the superposition of a uniform flow and doublet to yield the potential flow solution for non-lifting flow over a cylinder. 
[image]

Below each flow type is the associated stream function in polar coordinates. From the linearity of the Laplace equation, it then follows that the stream function for flow over a cylinder is thus,
$$ \psi = V_{\infty} r \sin \theta - \frac{\kappa}{2\pi} \frac{\sin \theta}{r} $$
where $V_{\infty}$ is the freestream velocity, and $\kappa$ is the strength of the doublet. It can be shown that the cylinder in question has a radius defined by,
$$ R^2 = \frac{\kappa}{2\pi V_{\infty}} $$
Re-writing the steam function in terms of $R$ yields,
$$\psi = \left(V_{\infty} r \sin \theta \right)\left(1 - \frac{R^2}{r^2}\right)$$
From the definition of the stream function we obtain,
$$ V_r = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta} = \left(1 - \frac{R^2}{r^2}\right)V_{\infty} \cos \theta$$
$$ V_{\theta} = -\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} = -\left(1 + \frac{R^2}{r^2}\right)V_{\infty} \sin \theta$$

At the stagnation point we have $V_r = V_{\theta} = 0$, hence,

$$ \left(1 - \frac{R^2}{r^2}\right)V_{\infty} \cos \theta = 0$$
$$ \left(1 + \frac{R^2}{r^2}\right)V_{\infty} \sin \theta = 0$$

Solving these equations yields two stagnation point solutions identified in the image above as points $A$ and $B$. These points correspond to $(r,\theta) = (R,0)$ and $(R,\pi)$, respectively. Many features can be deduced from the above results, but the most commonly desired is the gradient along the body in the vicinity of the stagnation point. Hence,
$$\frac{d V_{\theta}}{d\theta} = -\left(1 + \frac{R^2}{r^2}\right)V_{\infty} \cos \theta$$
where at the stagnation point of interest, $(r,\theta) = (R,\pi)$,
$$\frac{d V_{\theta}}{d\theta} = 2 V_{\infty} $$
Therefore, along the surface, we have,
$$\frac{d V_s}{ds} = \frac{2 V_{\infty}}{R} $$
This result is commonly required for boundary layer analysis in the vicinity of the stagnation point of a blunt nosed body. However, I am not sure exactly what you are seeking. Hopefully this will get you started in the right direction or at least provide some helpful pointers.

Comment: I wrote down what the answer has to be to the question. There is no need to actually solve for cylindrical geometry. The point here is that if you expand the solution for the cylinder around a stagnation point, you should recover the answer to my question.